# Query two indexes simultaneously in Kibana 4?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Whenever I create a visualization, Kibana 4 asks me to select the index for doing the search. My project requires searching data that is present in multiple indexes and hence I am stuck. I wish to search two indexes for my data and then visualize them. Any help would be valuable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kibana can create Visualization from multiple indexes. But! indexes should have similar names, or alias names with similar names, for example, you can simply grab data from indexes: **logstash-2015-01-01** and **logstash-2015-01-02** using mask **logstash-***.

But yes it would be handy if we could write something like **index1,onother_index**.

Answer (score 13):

A solution that works in any case: create an alias in Elasticsearch for the indexes you want to query simultaneously and then use the alias as an index-pattern in Kibana.

In the plugin Marvel, through the Sense interface, you can create an alias for multiple indexes by doing this request :

```
POST _aliases
{
    "actions" : [
      { "add" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } },
      { "add" : { "index" : "test2", "alias" : "alias1" } }
    ]
}
```

Or using CURL:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '
{
    "actions" : [
        { "add" : { "index" : "test1", "alias" : "alias1" } },
        { "add" : { "index" : "test2", "alias" : "alias1" } }
    ]
}'
```

Then, you just need to add an index-pattern in Kibana for "alias1" and create your visualizations.

For more informations on aliases, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Comment: alias is the right way too go, we are doing this, :)

Comment: I created an alias for two indexes , but discover doesnt show fields from both indexes. It still only shows rows from that index whose field I search for, If I put fields from both indexes I get blank rows.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for all the help, But I figured out a way in which this could be done.
In Index Pattern of Kibana 4 create an index Pattern as _all. This index pattern contains all the indexes present in your elasticsearch. Hence when you create a new visualization simply select the _all index pattern there and all the data fields from all the indexes in your elasticsearch are accessible and you can easily use it to create visualizations.

Comment: Did you move forward with this approach?  If so, how big are your data sets?  I am facing a similar issue but I am afraid that querying all indexes might hinder performance as my data grows.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, then it may depend on how you've named your indexes.

I can query multiple logstash indexes, by selecting my pattern 'logstash-*'. When you setup your indexes it gives you the option to specify a pattern.

(Settings => Indices => Index Pattern => Add New)

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Two wildcards (i.e. `*-*`) works for me in Kibana 4.

Comment: i found just `*` pulls in all the timelion and other internal ES indices but since i name all my indices `nginx-*` and `logstash-*` `*-*` captures just my actual indices. This is ES 6 on Kibana4 hosted on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand correctly, but I think your best option is to create that visualization on both indexes you want separately, and build a dashboard including both the visualizations.

Kibana can't display a single visualization with searches from two separate indexes.

Comment: Specifically this is Kibana 4, in Kibana 3 we have had success just specifying two index _patterns_ with a comma.  This is tracked under issue 2017: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/2017